# How to convert dataframe columns into a dictionary with one key and multiple value without tuples?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, zip

I got a large dataframe like that, which basically looks like this:

| Name | km | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | 24.6 | 43 | 555 |
| test | 63.9 | 31 | 666 |

which I would like to turn into a dictionary like:

```
{24.6: ["test",43,555],
63.9: ["test",31,666]}
```

What I found so far was https://stackoverflow.com/a/67496211/9218349, which would result in:

```
dict(zip(zip(df.km),zip(df.Name, df.Min,df.Max)))
```

this way i receive a dictionary of tuples, but I wont the keys to be floats and the values to be strings and floats. The floats should generally have 2 decimal places.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_dict('list')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) on the transposed DataFrame:

```
df.set_index('km').T.to_dict('list')
```

output:

```
{24.6: ['test', 43, 555], 63.9: ['test', 31, 666]}
```

*NB. note that in case you have duplicated values in "km", as you can only have unique keys in a dictionary, only the **latest** row will be kept*

Comment: awesome! quick, easy and exactly what I wanted, thanks !